# SELECT sql command error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query:

```
SELECT hrpersnl.p_empno AS a, hrpersnl.p_jobtitle AS b INTO abra2wfs
    FROM hrpersnl
    WHERE (((Left([hrpersnl].[p_empno],1))<>'A' And (Left([hrpersnl].[p_empno],1))<>'V') AND ((hrpersnl.p_active)<>'T' And (hrpersnl.p_active)<>'N'));
```

It works fine to get the data i need, but when i try to sort the row I get a "Syntax Error in Query". Now if I take the above code and change it to this:

```
    SELECT hrpersnl.p_empno AS a, hrpersnl.p_jobtitle AS b
FROM hrpersnl
WHERE (((Left([hrpersnl].[p_empno],1))<>'A' And (Left([hrpersnl].[p_empno],1))<>'V') AND ((hrpersnl.p_active)<>'T' And (hrpersnl.p_active)<>'N'));
```

I get the same output and i can also sort the two rows without any syntax error mentioned earlier.

Do i have the INTO command correct? Because to me it seems that's causing the error.

**Edit**:
What this query is suppose to do is, take all employees who are Active in our database and display their employee number and their job title.

Comment: Why do you want to sort a make table query?

Comment: i needed to export it in "a to z" format and also i think our database is throwing an error in another application which is co-existing with this query.

Comment: SELECT  ... INTO is a make table query, it creates a table, sort the table then export. Perhaps you could say a little more about what you are doing?

Comment: You do not want a make table query, just a query. If you want to sort, choose ORDER BY, or better, use the query design grid.

Comment: Well that works without any issue, it creates a table. Both queries does the function but why would one throw a syntax error if i try to sort? But is my first query correct?

Comment: `SELECT Field FROM Table` does not create a table, it displays rows from a table. `SELECT ... INTO` creates a new table. A relational database has no order other than that imposed by you, so a make table query does not need to be sorted, the table can be sorted after it has been created.

Comment: As Remou stated, there is no particular reason to sort the rows during your make table query; however, it is allowed - you can sort rows `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ... ORDER BY ...`. In your question you have provided the queries that work, but have not provided what does not work: you only say 'when I try to sort the row'. How are you sorting? In the query definition? Using the column headings in the table / query view?